# Freemarker: Remove particular attribute from node

Tags: freemarker

I have an XML node like this:

```
    <table version="1.0" border="1" rules="all" cellpadding="10">
        .
        .
        .
    </table>
```

I want Freemarker to "echo" this, but exclude the version attribute, giving this:

```
    <table border="1" rules="all" cellpadding="10">
        .
        .
        .
    </table>
```

I believe I need to use a macro something like this:

```
    <#macro table>
        <table [include all attributes except version]>
            <#recurse>
        </table>
    </#macro>
```

But I don't know what goes in the '[include all attributes except version]' section.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMarker's XML wrapper is not really for transforming XML to a similar XML, it's just a way of exposing data... But, if you stretch it a bit, it's possible after all (using http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/):

Template:

```
<#visit doc>

<#macro table>
  <table<@atts except=['a', 'c'] />>
    <#recurse>
  </table>
</#macro>

<#macro atts element=.node except=[]>
  <#list element.@@ as att>
    <#if !except?seqContains(att.@@qname)> ${att.@@qname}="${att?xml}"</#if><#t>
  </#list>
</#macro>
```

Data model:

```
doc=<table a="1" b='2' c='3' />
```

There are some traps in this, however, if you have attributes that belong to a namespace. Then you will need the prefixes to be declared with `<#ftl nsPrefixes="...">`.